# Rest Web Api XML Bind - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a post method in a rest asp net web api to receive data via json or xml. I need to deal with a specific xml structure that I can't change:

```
<data>
 <t>
    <id>sample string 1</id>
    <cnpj>sample string 2</cnpj>
    <datatransacao>sample string 3</datatransacao>
    <valorarredondado>sample string 4</valorarredondado>
    <grupo>sample string 5</grupo>
    <meiopagamento>sample string 6</meiopagamento>
    <parcelas>sample string 7</parcelas>
    <cpf>sample string 8</cpf>
    <nome>sample string 9</nome>
    <email>sample string 10</email>
    <codoperador>sample string 11</codoperador>
  </t>
  <t>
    <id>sample string 1</id>
    <cnpj>sample string 2</cnpj>
    <datatransacao>sample string 3</datatransacao>
    <valorarredondado>sample string 4</valorarredondado>
    <grupo>sample string 5</grupo>
    <meiopagamento>sample string 6</meiopagamento>
    <parcelas>sample string 7</parcelas>
    <cpf>sample string 8</cpf>
    <nome>sample string 9</nome>
    <email>sample string 10</email>
    <codoperador>sample string 11</codoperador>
  </t>
</data>
```

To achieve that I created a method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] string Token, [FromBody] List<t> data)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
}
```

It is basically a token and a List of t

```
public class t
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string cnpj { get; set; }
    public string datatransacao { get; set; }
    public string valorarredondado { get; set; }
    public string grupo { get; set; }
    public string meiopagamento { get; set; }
    public string parcelas { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string codoperador { get; set; }
}
```

With this, I`m getting a null value for the data parameter when testing. Everything binds correctly, only if a send:

```
<ArrayOfT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <t>
    <id>sample string 1</id>
    <cnpj>sample string 2</cnpj>
    <datatransacao>sample string 3</datatransacao>
    <valorarredondado>sample string 4</valorarredondado>
    <grupo>sample string 5</grupo>
    <meiopagamento>sample string 6</meiopagamento>
    <parcelas>sample string 7</parcelas>
    <cpf>sample string 8</cpf>
    <nome>sample string 9</nome>
    <email>sample string 10</email>
    <codoperador>sample string 11</codoperador>
  </t>
  <t>
    <id>sample string 1</id>
    <cnpj>sample string 2</cnpj>
    <datatransacao>sample string 3</datatransacao>
    <valorarredondado>sample string 4</valorarredondado>
    <grupo>sample string 5</grupo>
    <meiopagamento>sample string 6</meiopagamento>
    <parcelas>sample string 7</parcelas>
    <cpf>sample string 8</cpf>
    <nome>sample string 9</nome>
    <email>sample string 10</email>
    <codoperador>sample string 11</codoperador>
  </t>
</ArrayOfT>
```

My api is currently set to work with the Xmlserializer

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

In my tests I managed to serialize the xml by myself with the code:

```
var postStream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
postStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string postBodyString = new StreamReader(postStream).ReadToEnd();

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(postBodyString);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<t>), new XmlRootAttribute("data"));
List<t> ListOfT = (List<t>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to make the framework bind everything just considering the method`s signature with that xml. So far, I couldn't achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more class

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "t")]
    public List<t> data { get; set; }
}
```

Use it as parameter to your method. It should bind properly.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] string Token, [FromBody] Data data)
```

Also add XmlRoot attribute to your t class

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "t")]
public class t
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string cnpj { get; set; }
    ...
}
```